# send mails from cyclic with nodemailer and hostgatore

Tags: node.js, deployment, nodemailer

I have an app that send emails to the users when they lost the password, and then can restore.
I use hostgator email to send the emails.
I use app.cyclic.sh to deploy my backct
I would like to know if someone has some idea, why works in localhost and not in deployed mode.
I have all the variables upload and save in cyclic.
I have this code to send the email:

restoreEmail.js:

```
const transporter = require("./transporter");

const restorePasswordEmail = /* async */ (datos) => {
  const { nombre, email, id } = datos;
  console.log("DATOS MAIL", datos);
  const mailData = {
    from: "windymarket@windymarket.es",
    to: email,
    subject: "Recupera tu Contraseña",
    text: "Recupera tu Contraseña",
    html: `<p> Hola: ${nombre}, has solicitado reestablecer tu contraseña para tu cuenta en WindyMarket. </p>
        <p>Sigue el siguiente enlace para generar una nueva contraseña en: <a href="${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/forgotpassword/${id}">Resetear Password WindyMarket</a></p>        
        <p>Si tu no has registrado una cuenta en WindyMarket, no hagas caso de este correo, debe haber sido un error. 
        Disculpa las molestias </p>`,
  };
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    transporter.sendMail(mailData, function (error, response) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        resolve("email sent");
      }
    });
  });
};

module.exports = restorePasswordEmail;
```

transporter.js:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  name: "hostgator",
  host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
  port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
  },      
});

module.exports = transporter;
```

When i use it in localhost, works perfect, but when i use throw app.cyclic.sh where i deployed my backct, not works.
In the logs inside cyclic i don't have any error.
Just show me the first console.log("DATOS MAIL", datos);
but not the console inside the new Promise.

the funcion forgotPassword is the function that use the restorPasswordEmail:

```
exports.forgotPassword = async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  let user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "El Usuario no Existe" });
  } else {
    try {
      // Enviar Email con instrucciones
      restorePasswordEmail({
        id: user._id,
        email,
        nombre: user.nombre,
      });

      return res.status(200).json({ msg: "Hemos enviado un email con las instrucciones" });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
};
```

i dit try with async await, with promises, but not works in deployed mode.

thanks

Comment: i try to change my backserver from cyclic.sh to railway and works perfectly.
Something is not good setup in cyclic.sh to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to `await restorePasswordEmail`

---

also when you write

```
if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: "El Usuario no Existe" });
  }
```

you don't need an else statement since returning will end the function there

and you should wrap your whole function with try and catch

---

```js
exports.forgotPassword = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email } = req.body;

    let user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "El Usuario no Existe" });
    } 
    
      // Enviar Email con instrucciones
      await restorePasswordEmail({
        id: user._id,
        email,
        nombre: user.nombre,
      });

      return res.status(200).json({ msg: "Hemos enviado un email con las instrucciones" });
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: this solutions not works, 
something in cyclic, not want to send mails.
in railway works perfect, i think, that i change my backend server for now.